# DbVisualizer Cannot Find Database on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to connect to an SQL database, but am having a lot of trouble with it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

As you can see below, the location of the sql file is /Users/agoodkind/mockup/test-database.sql:
[image: Finder window]

In DbVisualizer, I have the following settings:
[image: Dbvisualizer screenshot]

The entirety of the Connection Message says:

> An error occurred while establishing the connection:
>
> Long Message: Unknown database
>   '/users/agoodkind/mockup/test-database.sql'
>
> Details:
>    Type: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
>     Error Code: 1049
>     SQL State: 42000

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**test-database.sql** is not an actual database it's most likely a text file of SQL statements to build a database.

Comment: Got it. So what should I do with it?

Comment: @Adam_G You should probably create a database and execute the SQL statements against that database.  The details of what exactly needs to be done would depend entirely on the source code you are working with.  I'm afraid you haven't provided enough information to be more specific.